# How to cancel setTimeout when navigate to another page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, settimeout

Good evening, could you please advise a solution to cancel setTimeout when user navigate to other pages (for example, click other links, press back button of browser, but not change to other tabs). I have tried window event "unload", but it seems not work as expected.

My app is a normal count down, if it count to 0, it will automatically navigate to assigned page. For some purpose, I need to disable this automatic navigate if user click on other links while it is counting. Thank you so much.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom";

const SucessPurchaseSubmit = () => {
    const history = useHistory();
    const navigateTo = () => history.push("/house-catalog");
    useEffect(() => {
        const time = document.querySelector(".time");
        let count = 10;
        var timer;
        // automatic navigate to full catalog after 10 seconds
        function countToNavigate(){
            clearTimeout(timer);
            time.innerHTML = count;
            if (count === 0) {
                navigateTo();
            }
            count -= 1;
            timer = setTimeout(countToNavigate, 1000)
        }
        countToNavigate();
        window.addEventListener("unload", () => {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        })
    })
    return (
        <section className="success-purchase-submit">
            <h1>Thank you so much for your information</h1>
            <h3>One of our consultants will contact you very shortly</h3>
            <h5>In the mean time, we will back to Full Catalog automatically after:</h5>
            <h5 className="time">10</h5>
        </section>
    );
};

export default SucessPurchaseSubmit;
```

Comment: no need to cancel a timeout when you leave a page

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. The case is that user is still in website, so it's not leaving page, it's just move from this url to another url on the same website.

Comment: The confusion here is because the user is navigating to a different client-side route in React and not a new page in the traditional sense.

Comment: beforeunload, not unload, in react if you change route, clear timer in router.

Comment: *to cancel setTimeout when user navigate to other pages* - no, I didn't misunderstand you at all

Comment: Have your timeout maintained in a global state, so that all of your routes have access to it.

Answer (score 3):

According to https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect , you can return a function from useEffect to do clean up when the component is unmounted.

So, at the end of the useEffect function, you  can probably add:

```
return () => clearTimeout(timer);
```

To cancel the timeout when the component is removed.

Answer (score 1):

I may have found a solution for your problem.

```
const FunctionalComponent = () => {
 React.useEffect(() => {
   return () => {
     console.log("Bye");
   };
 }, []);
 return <h1>Bye, World</h1>;
};
```

This is referred from - https://www.twilio.com/blog/react-choose-functional-components

You can use clearInterval() inside the useEffect().

The useEffect() works similar to the "OG" componentWillUnmount(). This is the perfect place to clearInterval() once redirecting to new page.